# While Restoring redshift from manual snapshot getting the error " The tag policy does not allow the specified value for the following tag key: 'WBS

Tags: amazon-redshift, snapshot

we have manual snapshot for redshift cluster. when we tried to restored it back we end up with getting the error " **The tag policy does not allow the specified value for the following tag key: 'WBS "**

we tried deleted all the associate tags in snapshot still getting the same issue.

we dont know where it exactly taking the tags value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Tag policies are configured from AWS Organizations. So in this case from the Master account is being applied the Tag policy that does not allows you create the cluster.

You can ask for allowed values for Tag "WBS" to an Administrator that have access to Master Account. Also you can get this values in AWS "Resource Groups & Tag Editor" service -> Tag Policies. It looks like this:
[image]